# JavaScript Object Call Not Working

Tags: javascript, object

I have a certain object created like this:

```
var classes = {

        login: {
            form: {
                wrapper:        'content-login',
                cls:            'login-form',
                fields:         'login-fields'
            },
            username: {
                wrapper:        'username-wrapper',
                label:          'user-img',
                input:          'username'
            },
            password: {
                wrapper:        'password-wrapper',
                label:          'pass-img',
                input:          'password'
            },
            button: {
                wrapper:        'login-wrapper',
                proceed:        'login'
            },
            toogle: {
                trigger: {
                    wrapper:    'toogle-button',
                    button:     'toogle'
                },
                buttons: {
                    wrapper:    'toogle-buttons',
                    twitter:    'twitter-login',
                    register:   'register',
                    recover:    'recover-password'
                }
            }   
        },

        register: {
            form: {
                wrapper:        'content-register',
                cls:            'register-form',
                fields:         'register-fields'
            },
            username: {
                wrapper:        'username-wrapper',
                label:          'username-label',
                input:          'username'
            },
            email: {
                wrapper:        'email-wrapper',
                label:          'email-label',
                input:          'email' 
            },
            password: {
                wrapper:        'password-wrapper',
                label:          'password-label',
                input:          'password'  
            },
            confirm: {
                wrapper:        'confirm-wrapper',
                label:          'confirm-label',
                input:          'confirm'
            },
            captcha: {
                wrapper:        'captcha-wrapper',
                label:          'captcha-label',
                input:          'captcha'
            },
            button: {
                wrapper:        'register-wrapper',
                message:        'message-handling',
                proceed:        'register'
            },
            back: {
                wrapper:        'back-button',
                button:         'back'
            }
        },

        recover: {
            form: {
                wrapper:        'content-recover',
                cls:            'recover-form',
                fields:         'recover-fields'
            },
            email: {
                wrapper:        'email-wrapper',
                label:          'email-label',
                input:          'email' 
            },
            button: {
                wrapper:        'recover-wrapper',
                proceed:        'recover'
            },
            back: {
                wrapper:        'back-button',
                button:         'back'
            }
        },

        reset: {
            form: {
                wrapper:        'content-reset',
                cls:            'reset-form',
                fields:         'reset-fields'
            },
            email: {
                wrapper:        'email-wrapper',
                label:          'email-label',
                input:          'email'
            },
            authcode: {
                wrapper:        'authcode-wrapper',
                label:          'authcode-label',
                input:          'authcode'  
            },
            password: {
                wrapper:        'password-wrapper',
                label:          'password-label',
                input:          'password'  
            },
            confirm: {
                wrapper:        'confirm-wrapper',
                label:          'confirm-label',
                input:          'confirm'
            },
            button: {
                wrapper:        'proceed-wrapper',
                message:        'message-handling',
                proceed:        'proceed'
            },
            back: {
                wrapper:        'back-button',
                button:         'back'
            }
        },

        success: {
            wrapper:            'after-login',
            message:            'row-one',
            buttons: {
                wrapper:        'row-two',
                cancel:         'cancel',
                proceed:        'continue'  
            }
        },

        lockdown: {
            wrapper:            'system-lockdown',
            message:            'row-one',
            buttons: {
                wrapper:        'row-two',
                back:           'back'
            }
        }

    }
```

And I'm trying to call a certain key like this:

```
classes[login.form.wrapper];
```

But it doesn't work that way, only like this:

```
classes.login.form.wrapper;
```

Or like this:

```
classes['login'];
```

Can someone tell me why it doesn't work like this :

```
classes[login.form.wrapper];
```

And can I make it work like that ? Because I have seen this method somewhere but I don't know if it is the same thing I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classes[login.form.wrapper];` is looking for an object named `login` in whatever scope the line of code runs in. That won't be found, because `login` is a property of `classes`. This will therefore throw a ReferenceError, because `login` is undefined.

If `login` was defined, and had a property named `form` which in turn had a property named `wrapper`, the value of that property would be used:

```
var login = {
        form: {
            wrapper: 'login'
        }
    };
console.log(classes[login.form.wrapper]); //Now this would return classes.login
```

`classes.login.form.wrapper;` works, because `classes` is an object with a property named `login`.

`classes['login'];` is equivalent to `classes.login`. You could write `classes['login']['form']['wrapper']` as an equivalent to `classes.login.form.wrapper`.

Comment: Yes, I have found that I cannot since I tried debugging with `try { ... } catch { ... }` and I saw that it gives me an ReferenceError, but, isn't there a way to make that work ? Because I have more than 500 lines of code to modify to the right way to make it work ?

Comment: @Roland - See my edit. You could create a `login` object with the appropriate properties, but that's very messy. I would suggest restructuring your code!

Comment: You mean doing `classes['login']['form']['wrapper']` . Well, if that's the case it means I will have to go through all of it and do that :(

Comment: @Roland - Sorry, I've got it wrong. You are going to have to change it all really!

Comment: No problem, I've written a PHP script that opens a text file and looks for every `[` and `]` occurrence and replaces it with `['` and `']` and also before that look for `.` inside `[ ... ]` and replace it with `][` and this did it all in a few milliseconds :) It's a good thing that I've got bored to do that manually and thought about doing a PHP script :D :) Thanks you for the info, I thought I had a bigger problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
classes['login']['form']['wrapper']
```

Code you are trying to invoke is just invalid:

```
classes[login.form.wrapper];
```

You are referring to the `login` variable that is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty much with your description.

What you basically want is to access a particular attribute, nested attributes in your case.

```
classes.login.form.wrapper;
```

This is quite intuitive to realize that, login is inside classes, form inside login and wrapper inside form.

JavaScript also allows you to use property names as indexes, as in:

```
classes['login'];
```

However, with

```
classes[login.form.wrapper];
```

It's actually implying to look for the attribute of `classes` whose name is stored in

```
login.form.wrapper
```

clearly, `login.form.wrapper`, doesn't exist on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

when you write

```
classes[login.form.wrapper];
```

an object login is expected.
as `login` is part of classes, you have to specify the whole 'path' to the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call object like this

classes[login.form.wrapper];

because login is key of your objects class, it will work like this

classes['login'] OR classes.login

Your key should not be like this : classes[login.form.wrapper];